# OOP Association: How to prevent multiple object ref. when reading data to Objects from Rel DB

Tags: oop

I am designing an OO approach in the software solution of my company and I am in doubt of how to 'consistently' save the data, prevent the same object from being created, where to save my object reference, ...

In general I have a Contract Pool and Accounts that belong to that Contract Pool. Both can exist without each other (Association). The Account can, in specific circumstances, belong to multiple Contract Pools.

1. Is saving a reference in both classes a good solution in temrs of data inconsistencies. (A refering to B, B not refering to A)
2. I would need instantiation from both sides.

   - Account->Get_Parents()
   - ContractPool->Get_Members()
3. Is there a way to prevent the creation of the same object. Example: ContractPool->Get_Members() as these calls trigger the database I get the ID's based on which I instantiate Contract Pool  / Account.

As awlays: If i'm posting in the wrong place, please guide me to the appropriate place.

If more information is required, I am happy to provide it.

Thanks in advance, Tom

### EDIT

This question / answer: stackoverflow.com/questions/16732607/… 
Along with: agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html

Provide a clear overview of how realtionship mapping is done. As a result the main question is:

'How do I prevent multiple references to the same object.'

Example: If I read the Contract Pools of an Account. Afterwards retrieve the members of the Contract Pools I want the reference of the preexisting Account to be the same.

However I read this date from the Database based on ID's. So I am not purely adding it to an array.

Comment: This question / answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732607/role-name-in-association-relationship
Along with:
http://agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html 

Provide a clear overview of how realtionship mapping is done.

As a result the main question is: 
'How do I prevent multiple references to the same object.'

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I gather that you want to ensure that the account objects referenced by the contract pool objects are the same that have been instantiated before and not new ones.

If this is so, all you need to do is instantiate the account objects first then associate them to the respective contract pool objects to which they belong.

I am sorry, I cannot give a more complete answer because your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is what I worked out so far. The problem is that my relationship should be available fro instantiation from both sides.

Account => Instantiate the Contract Pool
Contract pool => Instantiate the member Contract Pools / Accounts.

For the latter case: this is no issue because this instantiates everything top down. 

But for the first case: Account => Instantiates Parent => Parent Instantiates accounts how do I keep the reference here in check to the previous created account?

Comment: That you have to instantiate a bidirectional relationship is often a consequence of overthinking the solution. If you take each use-case separately, starting from the UI all the way to the data layer, you will probably see that there is none where you need to have each object reference each other at the same time. You will also see that the bidirectional relationship emerges when you reach the data layer because you are still subconsciously -- and wrongly -- trying to map your relational model onto ONE object model. (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) What you have to do is to design your objects specifically for each use-case. For example, if you are displaying accounts in a list, each with the associated contract pool name, you don't need to instantiate `Account` objects the associations to `ContractPool` objects; a more sensible approach is to create an `AccountListItem` that contains the name(s) of the contract pool(s) as a property -- no need to maintain an association with the contract pool object for this particular use-case.